# How do I take a block of text (with `\n`) from an object property and parse it as paragraphs?

Tags: javascript

The property is like this.

```
key: "paragraph.\n More text.\n Another sentence."
```

How would I show it like...

```
paragraph.

More text.

Another sentence.
```

without iterating or `split()`ting the text?

Number of paragraphs will be unknown at time of read. I have access to the object to rewrite the text in some other format, but it needs to stay as a single property.

I've tried

```
<p>{item["instruction"]}</p>
<p>{item.instruction}</p>
```

which both return solid blocks.

Comment: By replacing new line characters with HTML ones: `item.instruction.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')` or by making multiple paragraphs: `item.instruction.split('\n').map(txt => '<p>' + txt + '</p>')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example css ['white-space'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">{item.instruction}</p>
```

Or depending on what template library you use replace `\n` sign with `<br />` tag (but most template libs escape html when rendering the value).

Answer (score 0):

## **you can replace all `\n` in your string with `<br />` element**

*for replace all `\n` in your string you must use `RegExp` in `replace` method.*

```js
var key = "paragraph.\n More text.\n Another sentence."

// put result of this command in your html element
key.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
```